# Best Way to Schedule Update of ~100k records

Tags: callout, bulk

I have a custom object that I use to list all of the unique websites related to Accounts. There are about 100,000 records in this table. I'd like to schedule something like an Apex callout to update these.

I'm concerned about hitting limits, so I think this class will have to be scheduled in separate batches.

Which is this best solution for my need? Ideally, I'd like to have this all scheduled in Salesforce so I won't need a dedicated server running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a batchable class called from a scheduled class. It looks like this:

```
public class BatchScheduleProcess implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    public void execute(BatchableContext context, SObject[] records) {
        // Do your work here
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([ ... your query here ...]);
    }
    public void finish(BatchableContext context) {
        // Optional final cleanup/processing after all records are done
    }
}
```

From there, you can schedule it daily, weekly, monthly, etc using the UI, or with [System.schedule](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) to schedule other types of schedules, such as every few hours, etc.